# Passing SuperClass constructor parameters to a SubClass?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

Just beginning to start implementing Super and Sub classes to our projects but I'm having a bit of a problem creating the Subclass constructors to allow for different types of accounts but following the same rules as the Superclass.

Here is the constructor error I'm having.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7UUu.png

[image]

Comment: Isn't it like `super(firstName, lastName, accountNumber, street, town, postcode)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Account` class you have specified a constructor that takes multiple arguments: firstName, lastName, accountNumber etc..

In the constructor of the subclass you have to invoke the constructor of the super class -> `super()`

A little example:

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    /*constructor*/
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public String studentNumber;
    /*constructor*/
    public Student(String name, String studentNumber) {
        /* invoke super constructor. The parameters have to match the 
         * parameters specified in the constructor of Person
         */
        super(name);
        /* Now set the properties that only belongs to Student */
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Brilliant explanation I understand it much better now and have got my code to work :) here is my amended copy, you also reminded me how to use (this.parameter) 

http://i.imgur.com/MIG1o94.png